# What is the least invasive way to detect changes in a POJO?

Tags: java

Say I have a POJO, `public class Dog { ... }` -- would it be possible to have a listener detecting any changes to `Dog`? e.g. if `Dog` had a public String field that was initially "bark", and someone were to change it to "woof"; would it be possible for a listener to have caught that?

Comment: Your class should only have `private` fields, so your question is moot.

Comment: No. This would need either special preparation of the class or the field using e.g. `java.util.Observable` or a constant polling of the value (not recommended).

Comment: make all the fields "bound" properties using Java beans PropertyChangeSupport.

Comment: I came across https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern as well, but I wonder if there's something less invasive. Maybe something that involves reflections and proxies?